# How to Recover deleted Windows Partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, data-recovery

I wanted to delete ntfs partition in my dual boot and succeeded using Gparted. I increased the size of ubuntu ext4 partition by using unallocated space of recently deleted ntfs partition. 
Initially I had 300gb for ext4,  300 GB for ntfs and 600gb of unallocated space. Now it's 1000gb for ext4. 
But it turned out that I had some important data that I had forgotten about on windows. 
Is there any way to restore windows again? 
Currently I'm following these steps https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step.

Comment: TestDisk is pretty good. You're on the right track.